# What does 'beak trouble' mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Of course, I tried to look it up in a dictionary, but it didn't help. I assume it some kind of slang.

> "Hey, Lip. Everything okay?"
>
> "What, you got **beak trouble**, Charlie?"

*(from the 2018 movie Green Book)*

Comment: I bet it's an incorrect transcription of "big," which could be pronounced like "beak" in some accents. Does Lip have a strong accent in the movie?

Comment: @Justin He's an Italian

Comment: *beak* probably means ‘nose’. In England I believe *beak* can be slang for ‘judge’, but I wouldn't expect English slang in *Green Book*.